# Make the humanoid avatar always parallel to x-axis and facing -z direction in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, ergonomics

I am working with an external real-time motion capture system and stream the people real-time into Unity in the form of a skeleton avatar. So at any point, I have a tracked humanoid avatar in certain motions as done by the person.

I can access the skeleton/avatar joint values in Unity. I want to implement arm flexion(rotation angles in depth axis) values from another application for which in unity I want the skeleton(i.e shoulder left to right vector) to be always parallel to the x-axis and to be facing -z direction like this :
[image]

What I did :

I calculated the angle between the x-axis(1,0,0) and ShoulderLeft-ShoulderRight Vector and subtract it if it is more than 100 degrees or else add it to the original rotation of the skeleton value on y-axis. I am not doing this for every joints but only to the gameobject the skeleton is attached to.

```
double getParallelAngle = Vector3.Angle(shoulderLeft - shoulderRight, new Vector3(1, 0, 0));


            if(getParallelAngle > 0 && getParallelAngle < 100)
            {
                skeletonToRoatate.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(skeletonToRoatate.transform.eulerAngles.x, skeletonToRoatate.transform.eulerAngles.y + (float)getParallelAngle, skeletonToRoatate.transform.eulerAngles.z);
            }
            else
            {
                skeletonToRoatate.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(skeletonToRoatate.transform.eulerAngles.x, skeletonToRoatate.transform.eulerAngles.y - (float)getParallelAngle, skeletonToRoatate.transform.eulerAngles.z);
            }
```

Problem :

The skeleton seems to be always parallel to x-axis(with plus or minus few degrees which is not a big problem right now) but however it does not seem to be always looking in -z direction. How can I overcome this and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You want skeletonToRoatate to be always faced forward, like a Gimbal?

Comment: @PawełŁęgowski The angles I need to calculate require the skeleton to be aligned that way i.e. face looking forward -z direction and shoulder vector parallel to x-direction. I used ´transform.LookAt(transform.position - Vector3.forward, Vector3.up);´ it works for static skeleton but does not work for streamed skeleton with a pose

Answer (score 1):

[Vector3.Angle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html) always return a value between 0 and 180, no and doesn't matter the direction.

I'm not sure to really understand what's your goal but this could be the probleme here. You can use [Vector3.SignedAngle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SignedAngle.html) instead which given an axis, return a value between -180 and 180 degrees.